# Celery: How '|' operator works while chaining multi tasks?

Tags: python, celery, djcelery

I know `|` is a bitwise 'Or' operator but it makes me wonder that how it works in case of celery while chaining multiple tasks.

```
(first_task.s(url) | second_tasks.s()).apply_async()
```

I know that second task would take result of the first function as args but how's that possible? Where is '|' overloading in dj-celery source code?

```
@task
def second_task(results):
   do_something(results)
```

Can somebody please provide some insights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned above, Celery overrides the `__or__` operator, specifically as follows:

```
def __or__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, group):
        other = maybe_unroll_group(other)
    if not isinstance(self, chain) and isinstance(other, chain):
        return chain((self, ) + other.tasks, app=self._app)
    elif isinstance(other, chain):
        return chain(*self.tasks + other.tasks, app=self._app)
    elif isinstance(other, Signature):
        if isinstance(self, chain):
            return chain(*self.tasks + (other, ), app=self._app)
        return chain(self, other, app=self._app)
    return NotImplemented
```

The full implementation is here: https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/celery/canvas.py#L324

Answer (score 1):

They are likely using operator overloading as `__or__(self, other)`: http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html

I don't know the implementation details of Celery, but just to give you an idea:

```
class Task(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.chain = [self]

    def __or__(self, other):
        self.chain.append(other)
        return self

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

    def apply_async(self):
        for c in self.chain:
            print "applying", c


(Task('A') | Task('B') | Task('C')).apply_async()
```

Output:

```
applying A
applying B
applying C
```